# Google app engine terminate my functions

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I develop an app with Google App Engine, but I have a problem. The project is a research one and I have few heavy functions. Statistic analysis, natural language processing etc.

Few of the functions need more than 20 sec to finish.

One of them is an api of a website where I call a link and it return a dictionary. But, when I call it, after 4-5 sec, the browser stop loading and return an empty value. Nothing more.

If I run the function offline, out of the server, as a simple python function, I have the results after 10-15 sec.

Is there any way to increase the loading time or something else that will solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Google App Engine there is a hard timeout of 30sec per request so if you need more than that you will have to use [Task Queue API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or [Backends API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/).

The easiest way to achieve your goal though instead of messing around with Task Queue API is to use the [deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) which is a much simpler wrapper for it. After inserting the `- deferred: on` in your `app.yaml` you could do something like this (from the docs):

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

  def do_something_expensive(a, b, c=None):
    logging.info("Doing something expensive!")
    # Do your work here

  # Somewhere else
  deferred.defer(do_something_expensive, "Hello, world!", 42, c=True)
```

But since the task is going to be finished after your request you will have to write the result maybe somewhere in your Datastore to retrieve it later.

Answer (score 0):

actually, it sounds like you're hitting the urlFetch timeout first..

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/

```
You can set a deadline for a request, the most amount of time the
service will wait for a response. By default, the deadline for a
fetch is 5 seconds. The maximum deadline is 60 seconds for HTTP
requests and 10 minutes for task queue and cron job requests.
```

Update: you can set it with the deadline attribute..

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction

Comment: Is there any way to increase it?